# C Pointer Referencing

Tags: c, memory

I have the following code which simply prints out an introduction for a person's name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
}Person;

void intro(void *person){
    printf("The person you are looking for is %s %s\n", ((Person *)person)->firstname, ((Person *)person)->lastname);
}

int main()
{
    Person *a = NULL;
    a = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));

    char *first = NULL, *last = NULL;
    first = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    strncpy(first,"Bob", 20);
    last = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    strncpy(last,"Newmonson", 20)
    a->firstname = first;
    a->lastname = last;

    intro(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the output

`The person you are looking for is Bob Newmonson`

However changing `intro(a)` to `intro(&a)` produces

`The person you are looking for is �@ Newmonson`

When I open the first attempt in GDB and break on line 10 I find the address of `person=0x601010`. Both the first name and last name are stored where I would expect, `0x04006b9` and `0x4006bd` since they where declared earlier in the stack.

What gets me is when I run GDB with the changes made to `intro(&a)`. The address of `person` is now `0x7fffffffffdd38`, with the first name pointing to `0x601010` and the last name pointing to `0x4006db`.

Can anyone help explain to be what is going on and why I can still access the proper address of the last name in the second test.

**EDIT :**

As everyone seems to keep asking about it the `void *` was for a threading portion of this code that I did not include.

Comment: FYI:  `first = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20); first = "Bob";` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Also, why do you declare `intro()` as taking a `void*` when the only thing that has a hope of working with it is a `Person*`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I wanted to mess around with `void*` for practice but ran into this problem instead.

Comment: Cast person to an int and print it out. You'll see the value being held by the pointer. It should be the hex value you saw earlier.

Comment: @TimCooper As first I didn't think about what you where saying but then it dawned on me that my mallocs are getting completely overwritten by sticking `Bob` and `Newmanson` on the stack rather then using `strncpy` to copy what I want over to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `a` is already pointer to a `Person` structure; therefore `intro(&a)` passes a pointer to that pointer, but `intro()` treats it's argument as a pointer to `Person`.

Also, if `intro()` is intended to work on a Person, it should declare a `Person *` argument, not a `void *`.

Comment: The `void *` bit was coincidental as it had nothing to do with this problem initially.

Comment: @Blackninja543: Actually, the `void *` was material - had the function been more properly declared, the compiler would have warned you of a pointer type mismatch when using `intro(&a)`.  Using `void *` should be avoided - it's need is a big red flag that something is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The address being held inside of the pointer variable `a` is not the same as the address of the actual memory location being taken up by `a`.

And address like `0x601010` is a "low" memory address, and is going to typically be somewhere on the heap.  An address like `0x7fffffffffdd38` is a very "high" address, and will typically be on the stack.  So `&a` is giving you the actual address of the variable `a` on the stack, and it is passing that value to the function, not the value `0x601010` being stored inside the pointer variable `a`, and representing the first address of the allocated memory buffer returned from `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
/* allocate space for 20 characters and make 'first' point to that space. */
first = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
/* now make 'first' point to the string Bob. Leak the memory that was allocated before. */
first = "Bob";
/* Rinse, lather, repeat. */
last = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
last = "Newmonson";
```

Now to explain why using `intro(&a)` gives you unexpected results:

`intro` expects a pointer, which it assumes points to a structure of type `Person`. You create a pointer to a `Person` and then allocate space for it.

Calling `intro(a)` causes the pointer to `Person` to be passed as a pointer to `void` to intro, which then treats it as a pointer to `Person` and all is well.

Calling `intro(&a)` however takes the *address* of `a` and passes that in. Again, `intro` tries to treat it as a pointer to `Person` but that won't work because what you've passed is a pointer to a pointer to a `Person`. You're passing tomatoes to a function that thinks it's getting oranges. Both are fruit, and you will get juice, although you are probably not going to to be very happy when your breakfast is served with delicious tomato juice instead of delicious orange juice.

If you are asking why calling `intro(&a)` causes the first name to be mangled but the last name to be printed, the answer is because of sheer luck: the string with the last name just happened to be in the right position in memory.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
}Person;

void intro(Person *person){
    printf("The person you are looking for is %s %s\n", (person)->firstname,   (person)->lastname);
}

int main()
{
    Person *a = NULL;
    char *first = NULL, *last = NULL;
    a = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));


    first = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    first = "Bob";
    last = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    last = "Newmonson";
    a->firstname = first;
    a->lastname = last;

    intro(a);

    return 0;
}
```

hope it helps...

Comment: Why are you casting a `Person *` to a `Person *`?

Comment: I know its Unnecessary, but I belive its good habit, to calm the compiler :P

Comment: Come again? I have no idea what that means.

Comment: it doesnt hurt the code (I think), I just didnt want to change his too much. but u a right its unnecessary

Comment: It absolutely is **not** a good habit, in fact it's a ***really, really bad*** habit.  Use casts in C only when the compiler complains and you *know* you know better than the compiler... and even then, double check your assumptions.